# Mark region of a plot by a rectangle

Tags: plotting

I want to make a series of plots, each of which will show a zoomed on region of the plot before.

So that everything is easy to understand, I want to mark the region which will be seen in the next plot by a dotted rectangle.

How can I draw this rectangle?

As an example: Say I want to plot sin(x), and then mark the region like in this picture here:

[image]

Comment: `PlotRange` to set the plot range, `Epilog` with `Dashed` and `Rectangle` to mark the region. Please look them up along with http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html and related tutorials.

Comment: Take a look at [140090](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140090/5478), is this what you need?

Comment: See also this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195664/plotting-a-graph-of-a-function-and-part-of-it/195675#195675

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you very much! This is what I needed. One follow up question: I now did it with `Show` and then `Plot` for the function plot on the one hand, and `Graphics` + `Rectangle` for the region on the other hand. What is the benefit by doing it with `Epilog` instead of `Show`?

Comment: @Kuba This is actually even more advanced! So far I am happy with only marking the region, and then make a second plot for the zoomed in part. But I will keep this in mind for the future to make even nicer plots. Thanks for linking!

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci This is actually even more advanced! So far I am happy with only marking the region, and then make a second plot for the zoomed in part. But I will keep this in mind for the future to make even nicer plots. Thanks for linking!

Comment: I think `Show` is fine here (either is fine).

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a combination of [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html), [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) and [`Locator`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locator.html) in a [`DynamicModule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html):

```
plt = Plot[ Cos[ 3 Sin[2 x] x] x, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];

DynamicModule[{pts = {{-3, -3}, {4, 3}}}, 
 Show[plt, 
  Epilog -> Dynamic @ {Directive[EdgeForm[{Red, Dashed}], Lighter@Yellow, Opacity[.3]],
     Dynamic[Rectangle @@ pts], 
     MapThread[Locator[Dynamic[pts[[#]]], 
        Graphics[{#2, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 8], 
        LocatorRegion -> Full] &, {{1, 2}, {Black, Gray}}]}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively define a function `zoom`  to define a rectangle with interactively adjustable coordinates:

```
ClearAll[zoom]
zoom[Dynamic[coords_], edgestyle_: Orange, facestyle_: LightYellow] :=
  Graphics[{Directive[EdgeForm[{edgestyle, Dashed}], facestyle, Opacity[.3]], 
   Dynamic[Rectangle @@ coords], 
   MapThread[Locator[Dynamic[coords[[#]]], 
        Graphics[{#2, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 8], LocatorRegion -> Full] &,
     {{1, 2}, {Black, Gray}}]}]
```

You can use `zoom` with a single plot:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = Transpose @ PlotRange[plt]/2}, 
 Show[plt, zoom[Dynamic @ pts, Red, Lighter @ Lighter @ Red]]]
```

[image]

To get a series of plots each zooming on a region of the previous one, we can use `zoom` as a helper function as follows:

```
ClearAll[shrink, paneled, zoompanels]
shrink[s_] := {##} + {-1, 1} s Subtract[##]/2 &;

paneled = Panel[#, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, Alignment -> Center] &;

zoompanels[plt_, sh_: .25] := DynamicModule[{pta = Transpose[PlotRange[plt]], 
   ptb = Transpose[shrink[sh] @@@ PlotRange[plt]]}, 
  Row[paneled /@ {Show[plt, zoom[Dynamic[pta]]], 
    ptb = Transpose[shrink[sh] @@@ Transpose[pta]]; 
   Framed[Show[plt, zoom[Dynamic[ptb], Blue, LightBlue],
     PlotRange -> Dynamic[Transpose[pta]]], FrameStyle -> Orange], 
   Framed[Show[ plt, PlotRange -> Dynamic[Transpose[ptb]]], 
     FrameStyle -> Blue]}]]
```

Using `zoompanels` to create cascading zooms:

```
Deploy @ zoompanels[plt]
```

[image]